# How to display double curly braces with Angular

Tags: html, angularjs, entity

I've been trying to use HTML entities to avoid Angular making binding when plaintext hits {{}}

So I've discovered that browser converts them to plain curvy braces anyway. Here is plain sample. As you can see in DOM inspector, HTML entity codes were converted to simple curvy braces. Is it specified somewhere?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OxEeqg

```
<body>
  &#123;&#123;1+2&#125;&#125;
</body>
```

Upd: Chrome and FF behave similar in this situation.

Comment: That is the intended behaviour. If you want to display your line literally you'll have to turn for example the `&` into an entity as well: `&amp;#123;&amp;#123;1+2&amp;#125;&amp;#125;`

Comment: No, I am speaking not about displayed. The HTML in the DOM itself is converted. I wanted it to be displayed as curvy braces, but not identified by Angular expression parser. As results I have had to insert ZWSP between first two braces, but I am still curious why `&#123;` is converted to `{` *in the HTML source*

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ng-non-bindable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable) directive on a wrapper element:

```
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1+2}}</span>
```

If you use it on a container element, you can also ignore attributes:

```
<div ng-non-bindable>
    <input value="{{example}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately same element have attributes where I do need binding and its descendands have them too. But the most important thing that it is XSS in fact and I don't want to prevent XSS by blacklisting. I wanted solution working everywhere whether I forgot to add `ng-non-bindable` or not. So I've added hook on save to database and thought it was working fine until I found that replacing curvy braces with just HTML entities doesn't work because browser replaces them back.

Answer (score 1):

To do it in Angular way, I would suggest the below.

Simply by providing ANY desired characters as a string inside interpolation.

`<div>What ever you want to show can be given inside this {{ "{ } ' {1+2} " }} </div>`

Output:

What ever you want to show can be given inside this { } ' {1+2}

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a solution for the latest Angular.
In Angular 2 this became the `ngNonBindable` directive.

```
<span ngNonBindable>{{example}}</span>
```